# How to print the pop up window content with the main content

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, popup

I want to print the content of my page. But that contain a popup. I need to display the pop up window content in my main page contain a button name Details. When I click the button a pop up will show.

When I click my print button.Only show the main content. The particular field for the pop up displaying window is blank (Details button)

I'm using  `window.print();`

print button=>     'onclick="printpage()"'

**function**

```
function printpage()
{
    $('#hiddendiv').html($('#view_popup_descriptive_index').html()); 
    $('#hiddendiv').show();
    window.print();
    $('#hiddendiv').hide();
}
```

Any method to display the popup content.

Comment: can you add fiddle or elaborate you problem

Comment: Again, the same question. Do you have your popup content on the main page? You cannot print a popup content with the main page unless it is visible on screen

Comment: Rose, please add a snippet or fiddle or bin so it will be easier to us to understand your wish..

Comment: Mosh Feu,i have to print a table structure contain datas..The table contains students details..One of the column name is Details.that button shows on each student.When click the button display a popup that contain some description

Comment: so, the popup disappears when you click the 'print' button, is that correct? what plugin do you use for popups?

Comment: Normally when i click the print button print only the main content.The popup will display through a button click.My requirement is that show the popup content also

Comment: what you need to do is either a) trigger the `click` event on the `Details` button before the `window.print();` call; or b) if you are using any plugin to show popups, find the corresponding API method that can show the popup programmatically

Comment: yaa..thats right.I need the first one.I will show u what i'm trying

Comment: @Rose, so does you snippet work? It looks like it should

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101752/discussion-between-rose-and-skip405).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try appending the HTML from the popup to the page before printing.

```
$("#print").on('click', function(){
    //find HTML
  var $popupContent = $('.popup').html();

  //console.log($popupContent); //see what you really get from the popup

  //create a div before the button and put the popup content there
  $(this).before($('<div />', {
    'class': 'created',
    'html': $popupContent
  }));

  //trigger printing
  window.print();

  //remove the dynamically created container
  $('.created').remove();
})
```

You can see it working online here - https://jsfiddle.net/skip405/6dt2dhm7/

Comment: i need ur help.Plz help me

Comment: @Rose, what's the problem?